# phpmyadmin, automating import, sql & export

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use phpmyadmin to `import` a file that was created with `mysqldump`. Then I run a few lines of sql on the data, including a line which creates a view. Then I `export` the view as a `csv`.

Can I automate that in any way? I don't see any way to do it, from looking within phpmyadmin or doing a websearch.

Failing that, does phpmyadmin at least have any way to save sql queries?

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is not really the right tool for automation. You better do that using cron and mysql command line tool.

Comment: That is not an option on some hosts, and unfortunately (or, fortunately?) phpMyAdmin seems to reject automated logins entirely (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176974)

Comment: There is no intention to automatically reject logins in phpMyAdmin. Anyway the question you've referenced no longer exists - This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad question - I had mistyped, sending pma_user parameter, not the required pma_username.